# What condition should we write to get gaps between dates at least 28 days?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am writing a code in which I have taken start date and end date as input.(and want to show date between these range) Now I want to make sure that the gap between these two dates should be greater than 28 days i.e. 4 week. If user giving two dates having gap of 5 days then the start date should be change accordingly.

I tried some if else conditions but not getting the desired result.

```
***
if(enddate == DateTime.Now.Date){ startdate = ed.AddDays(-28);}
else if(enddate < )
else if()
else
***
```

What should be the other conditions?

Comment: What do you mean with "start date should be change accordingly"

Comment: Accordingly means I want to change the startdate to make sure the gap between the dates should be 28 days (Not less than that) and the enddate should be same as provided by user.

Comment: `enddate == DateTime.Now.Date` is never going to work, whats the chance of `enddate` being in the exact same millisecond as now?

Comment: `startdate = enddate.AddDays(-28);` why isn't this working? this question is becoming unclear

Comment: @TheGeneral For your first comment. You told the problem which I agree is a mess. But what should be the solution to check the condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
var startdate = DateTime.Now;
var enddate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
if((enddate-startdate).Days<28)
{
    startdate = enddate.AddDays(-28);
}
```

After `if` statement the gap between `startdate` and `enddate` will be at least 28 days

Comment: that's right, but what if the gap is more than 28 days. Now if I want the gap strictly 28 days ?? what will be the condition?

Comment: @Sudhir if you want the gap to be strictly 28 days, then why do you need a condition at all? You're saying that you _always_ want the gap to be 28 days.

Comment: @John Yep you are right. That's not the case anyway. just asked out of curiosity.

Comment: if you want the gap always remain 28 days then there is no need for `if` statement. And no need to input `startdate`. Only one input `enddate` is enough. You can evaluate `startdate` by subtracting 28 days from `enddate`